# How to correct overlapping text in pill

Tags: html, css, nav-pills

https://jsbin.com/dizixeg/edit?output

I've quick copied HTML/CSS to jsBin using [SnappySnippet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/snappysnippet/blfngdefapoapkcdibbdkigpeaffgcil).

I have tried doing, with no use. Best can work for me `overflow:ellipses`

1. word-break: break-word;
2. word-break: break-all;
3. white-space: pre;
4. text-overflow: ellipsis;

Here is my code

```css
#DIV_1 {
    bottom: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    float: left;
    height: 163px;
    left: 0px;
    min-height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    width: 665px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    perspective-origin: 332.5px 81.5px;
    transform-origin: 332.5px 81.5px;
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
    padding: 0px 15px;
}/*#DIV_1*/

#DIV_1:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_1:after*/

#DIV_1:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_1:before*/

#LABEL_2 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 28px;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    width: 56.25px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    perspective-origin: 28.125px 14px;
    transform-origin: 28.125px 14px;
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 18px / normal rajdhaniregular;
    margin: 0px 0px 5px;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#LABEL_2*/

#LABEL_2:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 18px / normal rajdhaniregular;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#LABEL_2:after*/

#LABEL_2:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 18px / normal rajdhaniregular;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#LABEL_2:before*/

#DIV_3 {
    bottom: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    height: 130px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    width: 635px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    perspective-origin: 317.5px 65px;
    transform-origin: 317.5px 65px;
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
    overflow: auto scroll;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}/*#DIV_3*/

#DIV_3:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_3:after*/

#DIV_3:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_3:before*/

#DIV_4 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    height: 27px;
    min-width: 60px;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    width: 597px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    perspective-origin: 298.5px 13.5px;
    transform-origin: 298.5px 13.5px;
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
    margin: 14px 10px 2px;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_4*/

#DIV_4:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_4:after*/

#DIV_4:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_4:before*/

#DIV_5 {
    bottom: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    height: 28px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    width: 597px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    perspective-origin: 298.5px 14px;
    transform-origin: 298.5px 14px;
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 1px solid rgb(215, 215, 215);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
    margin: 0px 0px 20px;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
    padding: 14px 15px 0px 5px;
    transition: opacity 0.15s linear 0s;
}/*#DIV_5*/

#DIV_6 {
    bottom: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
    float: right;
    height: 27px;
    left: 15px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: relative;
    right: -15px;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(101, 101, 101);
    text-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 1px 0px;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    top: -15px;
    width: 27.7969px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
    perspective-origin: 13.8906px 13.5px;
    transform-origin: 13.8984px 13.5px;
    caret-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
    border-top: 0px none rgb(101, 101, 101);
    border-right: 0px none rgb(101, 101, 101);
    border-bottom: 0px none rgb(101, 101, 101);
    border-left: 1px solid rgb(215, 215, 215);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 30px / 32px rajdhaniregular;
    outline: rgb(101, 101, 101) none 0px;
    padding: 0px 6px;
}/*#DIV_6*/

#DIV_6:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(101, 101, 101);
    text-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 1px 0px;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    column-rule-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
    caret-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
    border: 0px none rgb(101, 101, 101);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 30px / 32px rajdhaniregular;
    outline: rgb(101, 101, 101) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_6:after*/

#DIV_6:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(101, 101, 101);
    text-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 1px 0px;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    column-rule-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
    caret-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
    border: 0px none rgb(101, 101, 101);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 30px / 32px rajdhaniregular;
    outline: rgb(101, 101, 101) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_6:before*/

#SPAN_7 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    perspective-origin: 0px 0px;
    transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#SPAN_7*/

#SPAN_7:after {
    word-wrap:
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#SPAN_7:after*/

#SPAN_7:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#SPAN_7:before*/

#DIV_8 {
    bottom: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    perspective-origin: 0px 0px;
    transform-origin: 0px 0px;
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
    margin: -6px 0px 0px;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_8*/

#DIV_8:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_8:after*/

#DIV_8:before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
    text-size-adjust: 100%;
    column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
    font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
    outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}/*#DIV_8:before*/
```

```html
<div id="DIV_1">
  <label id="LABEL_2">
    Invitees
  </label>
  <div id="DIV_3">
    <div id="DIV_4">
      <div id="DIV_5">
        <div id="DIV_6">
          ×
        </div>
        <span id="SPAN_7">A very very long name A very very long name A very very long name &lt;longname@longname.com&gt;</span>
        <div id="DIV_8">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="DIV_5">
        <div id="DIV_6">
          ×
        </div>
        <span id="SPAN_7">Normal length contact&lt;contact@somname.com&gt;</span>
        <div id="DIV_8">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want the display to look like?

Comment: Don't use equal IDs on a single page. If you really need it, use classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex box with ellipsis should fix your problem,

```
#DIV_5 {
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
#DIV_6 {
    order: 2;
    top: -6px;
}
#SPAN_7 {
    line-height: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution using `text-overflow:ellipsis` (the new CSS is at the bottom of the code, under the *Fix* comment).

As a general advice, I would simplify the structure of the code to make it easier to handle.

```css
#DIV_1 {
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  float: left;
  height: 163px;
  left: 0px;
  min-height: 1px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 665px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 332.5px 81.5px;
  transform-origin: 332.5px 81.5px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
  margin: 0px 0px 15px;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}


/*#DIV_1*/

#DIV_1:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_1:after*/

#DIV_1:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_1:before*/

#LABEL_2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 28px;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: 56.25px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 28.125px 14px;
  transform-origin: 28.125px 14px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 18px / normal rajdhaniregular;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#LABEL_2*/

#LABEL_2:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 18px / normal rajdhaniregular;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#LABEL_2:after*/

#LABEL_2:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 18px / normal rajdhaniregular;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#LABEL_2:before*/

#DIV_3 {
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  height: 130px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 635px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 317.5px 65px;
  transform-origin: 317.5px 65px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
  overflow: auto scroll;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}


/*#DIV_3*/

#DIV_3:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_3:after*/

#DIV_3:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_3:before*/

#DIV_4 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  height: 27px;
  min-width: 60px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: 597px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 298.5px 13.5px;
  transform-origin: 298.5px 13.5px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
  margin: 14px 10px 2px;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_4*/

#DIV_4:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_4:after*/

#DIV_4:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_4:before*/

#DIV_5 {
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  height: 28px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 597px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 298.5px 14px;
  transform-origin: 298.5px 14px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 1px solid rgb(215, 215, 215);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
  margin: 0px 0px 20px;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
  padding: 14px 15px 0px 5px;
  transition: opacity 0.15s linear 0s;
}


/*#DIV_5*/

#DIV_6 {
  bottom: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
  float: right;
  height: 27px;
  left: 15px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: relative;
  right: -15px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(101, 101, 101);
  text-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 1px 0px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: -15px;
  width: 27.7969px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
  perspective-origin: 13.8906px 13.5px;
  transform-origin: 13.8984px 13.5px;
  caret-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
  border-top: 0px none rgb(101, 101, 101);
  border-right: 0px none rgb(101, 101, 101);
  border-bottom: 0px none rgb(101, 101, 101);
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(215, 215, 215);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 30px / 32px rajdhaniregular;
  outline: rgb(101, 101, 101) none 0px;
  padding: 0px 6px;
}


/*#DIV_6*/

#DIV_6:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(101, 101, 101);
  text-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 1px 0px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
  caret-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
  border: 0px none rgb(101, 101, 101);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 30px / 32px rajdhaniregular;
  outline: rgb(101, 101, 101) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_6:after*/

#DIV_6:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(101, 101, 101);
  text-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 1px 0px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
  caret-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
  border: 0px none rgb(101, 101, 101);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 30px / 32px rajdhaniregular;
  outline: rgb(101, 101, 101) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_6:before*/

#SPAN_7 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 0px 0px;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#SPAN_7*/

#SPAN_7:after {
  word-wrap: box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#SPAN_7:after*/

#SPAN_7:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#SPAN_7:before*/

#DIV_8 {
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 0px 0px;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
  margin: -6px 0px 0px;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_8*/

#DIV_8:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_8:after*/

#DIV_8:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_8:before*/


/* Fix */
#DIV_5 {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
}

#SPAN_7 {
  line-height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div id="DIV_1">
  <label id="LABEL_2">
    Invitees
  </label>
  <div id="DIV_3">
    <div id="DIV_4">
      <div id="DIV_5">
        <div id="DIV_6">
          ×
        </div>
        <span id="SPAN_7">A very very long name A very very long name A very very long name &lt;longname@longname.com&gt;</span>
        <div id="DIV_8">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="DIV_5">
        <div id="DIV_6">
          ×
        </div>
        <span id="SPAN_7">Normal length contact&lt;contact@somname.com&gt;</span>
        <div id="DIV_8">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code - text-overflow:ellipsis

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#DIV_1 {
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  float: left;
  height: 163px;
  left: 0px;
  min-height: 1px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 665px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 332.5px 81.5px;
  transform-origin: 332.5px 81.5px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
  margin: 0px 0px 15px;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
  padding: 0px 15px;
}


/*#DIV_1*/

#DIV_1:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_1:after*/

#DIV_1:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_1:before*/

#LABEL_2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 28px;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: 56.25px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 28.125px 14px;
  transform-origin: 28.125px 14px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 18px / normal rajdhaniregular;
  margin: 0px 0px 5px;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#LABEL_2*/

#LABEL_2:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 18px / normal rajdhaniregular;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#LABEL_2:after*/

#LABEL_2:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 18px / normal rajdhaniregular;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#LABEL_2:before*/

#DIV_3 {
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  height: 130px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 635px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 317.5px 65px;
  transform-origin: 317.5px 65px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
  overflow: auto scroll;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}


/*#DIV_3*/

#DIV_3:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_3:after*/

#DIV_3:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_3:before*/

#DIV_4 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  height: 27px;
  min-width: 60px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  width: 597px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 298.5px 13.5px;
  transform-origin: 298.5px 13.5px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
  margin: 14px 10px 2px;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_4*/

#DIV_4:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_4:after*/

#DIV_4:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 14px / 20px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_4:before*/

#DIV_5 {
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  height: 28px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 597px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 298.5px 14px;
  transform-origin: 298.5px 14px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 1px solid rgb(215, 215, 215);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
  margin: 0px 0px 20px;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
  padding: 14px 15px 0px 5px;
  transition: opacity 0.15s linear 0s;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}


/*#DIV_5*/

#DIV_6 {
  bottom: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
  float: right;
  height: 27px;
  left: 15px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  position: relative;
  right: -15px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(101, 101, 101);
  text-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 1px 0px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: -15px;
  width: 27.7969px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
  perspective-origin: 13.8906px 13.5px;
  transform-origin: 13.8984px 13.5px;
  caret-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
  border-top: 0px none rgb(101, 101, 101);
  border-right: 0px none rgb(101, 101, 101);
  border-bottom: 0px none rgb(101, 101, 101);
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(215, 215, 215);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 30px / 32px rajdhaniregular;
  outline: rgb(101, 101, 101) none 0px;
  padding: 0px 6px;
}


/*#DIV_6*/

#DIV_6:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(101, 101, 101);
  text-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 1px 0px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
  caret-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
  border: 0px none rgb(101, 101, 101);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 30px / 32px rajdhaniregular;
  outline: rgb(101, 101, 101) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_6:after*/

#DIV_6:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(101, 101, 101);
  text-shadow: rgb(255, 255, 255) 0px 1px 0px;
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
  caret-color: rgb(101, 101, 101);
  border: 0px none rgb(101, 101, 101);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 30px / 32px rajdhaniregular;
  outline: rgb(101, 101, 101) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_6:before*/

#SPAN_7 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 0px 0px;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#SPAN_7*/

#SPAN_7:after {
  word-wrap: box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#SPAN_7:after*/

#SPAN_7:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#SPAN_7:before*/

#DIV_8 {
  bottom: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: relative;
  right: 0px;
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  perspective-origin: 0px 0px;
  transform-origin: 0px 0px;
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
  margin: -6px 0px 0px;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_8*/

#DIV_8:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_8:after*/

#DIV_8:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-decoration: none solid rgb(51, 51, 51);
  text-size-adjust: 100%;
  column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  caret-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  border: 0px none rgb(51, 51, 51);
  font: normal normal 400 normal 16px / 0px rajdhanimedium;
  outline: rgb(51, 51, 51) none 0px;
}


/*#DIV_8:before*/
```

```html
<div id="DIV_1">
  <label id="LABEL_2">Invitees</label>
  <div id="DIV_3">
    <div id="DIV_4">
      <div id="DIV_5">
        <div id="DIV_6">×</div>
        <span id="SPAN_7">A very very long name A very very long name A very very long name &lt;longname@longname.com&gt;</span>
        <div id="DIV_8"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="DIV_5">
        <div id="DIV_6">×</div>
        <span id="SPAN_7">Normal length contact&lt;contact@somname.com&gt;</span>
        <div id="DIV_8"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```